# Какой модуль Gulp лучше использовать для мультиязычности

Tags: html, gulp, i18n

Подскажите, какой модуль Gulp умеет создавать из одного файла несколько файлов с использованием нужных переменных. Например, нужно мне 2 языка на сайте, то я хочу просто добавить что-то типа "Наверх|Top" и должно создаться 2-файла index.html с значением "Наверх" и index.html_en со значением "Top"

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно будет будет плагинар gulp-rename (если я верно понял ваш вопрос). 
Пример кода:

```
   gulp.task('html', function() {
    gulp.src(path.src.htmlEn)
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '_en'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.htmlEn))
   });
```

Если ответ не верен, раскройте понятие мультиязычности в вашем вопросе, что вам нужно. 
P.S. Если нужен автоматический перевод через Gulp - реализовать невозможно.

Comment: Автоматически не надо, нужно просто чтобы в одной кодовой базе были все изменения но фронты собирались через файл маппинга или типа того.